# How best to do a codebase-wide find only on *displayed* instances of a string in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, replace

In several places in a rather complex Rails app there are references to a particular kind of object; let's call them "apples". I'd like to change all of these user-facing references from "apples" to "oranges". This would be simple enough, except that I'd like to retain `Apple` as class, so I don't want to touch the myriad methods, variables, symbols, etc. that use the word "apple".

There are several orders of magnitude more instances of `apple` in the code proper than there are user-facing instances of "apple". My question is: How can I zero in on the relatively few displayed instances? Is there a way to perform a search on all and only what is *displayed* by a browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've taken a disciplined approach to separate your language from your code, such as using localization files, then no, there's no easy way to find instances of displayed text. How is a search supposed to differentiate between `'apple'` used as a type column and `'apple'` inserted into a page?

This is why you might want to take an approach where you don't embed language in your controllers and models. Instead you could create a helper method to describe them for you:

```
You have <%= pluralize_model(@apple, 10) %> left.
```

That method, if constructed properly, would render `'10 apples'` or whatever term you'd like to use for that type of object.